# Permissions issue when using copy module in Ansible on Mac

Tags: macos, ansible, osx-elcapitan, ansible-2.x

I am trying the following task from a role in Ansible v2.2.1 running on Mac OS X v10.11.6 but I am getting a permissions issue (copied below):

```
  - name: Create the test scripts
    copy:
      src: "usr_bin_{{item}}"
      dest: "/usr/bin/{{item}}"
      owner: root
      group: wheel
      mode: 0755
    with_items: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    become_user: root
```

**error**

```
failed: [localhost] (item=abc) => {"checksum": "44b300f4a9334ca0e34d0e5b3e2c121c76214f7c", "failed": true, "item": "abc", "msg": "Destination /usr/bin not writable"}
failed: [localhost] (item=def) => {"checksum": "dcd44e71b93f303c5d9abfcecd48c8637eabeeaa", "failed": true, "item": "def", "msg": "Destination /usr/bin not writable"}
failed: [localhost] (item=ghi) => {"checksum": "b9c28df8772702ba9b4b7d05e24c972aa536bdc3", "failed": true, "item": "ghi", "msg": "Destination /usr/bin not writable"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot freely write to `/usr/bin` on OS X / macOS (since El Capitan) - read about [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899).

The common practice is to use `/usr/local/bin` instead, but you need to add it to `PATH`. Mind that Homebrew package manager assumes (by default) subdirectories of `/usr/local` should be writable by a regular user, not `root`.